# Qt "SOCKS version 5 protocol error" proxy error

Tags: qt, proxy, socks

When I try to connect over Socks5Proxy:

```
QNetworkProxy proxy;
proxy.setType(QNetworkProxy::Socks5Proxy);
proxy.setHostName("free socks proxy address");
proxy.setPort(60088); //for example

QNetworkAccessManager *webCtrl = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
webCtrl->setProxy(proxy);
```

I receive an error (QNetworkReply::UnknownNetworkError) - "SOCKS version 5 protocol error".
With HttpProxy all work fine.